# Is it safe to "cap" a disconnected doorbell wire using electrical tape?

Tags: electrical, safety, doorbell

I recently decided to disconnect my doorbell to stop it from waking up the family. I removed the doorbell from the outside of the house and disconnected one of the two pairs of wires that were connected to it (two pairs of two wires, each pair connected to one screw). This disabled the doorbell just fine, but I am worried about the way I "capped" the live wire using electrical tape. Since the wire nuts I have don't fit inside the doorbell this was the best I could come up with. Once wrapped in electrical tape, I tucked the wire back into the doorbell casing, screwed the one screw back in, and reattached the whole thing to the house. Is this safe? Everything I have found online mentions that it is safe due to the wire being low voltage. This is a new doorbell on a new home, if that makes a difference.

[Reference](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/disable-doorbell-48807.html)

> All doorbells have a transformer that changes 120 volts of household
>   electricity into 24 volts of electricity.or less. This low voltage is
>   not dangerous and wrapping the wires that come off the transformer
>   with electrical tape is a safe way to seal the wires. Tiny wire nuts
>   can be used for the same purpose.

**Edit**

I am in the United States, MN specifically.

Comment: I would disconnect the power to the transformer for a "safe" way to turn the doorbell off or even install a small toggle switch on the secondary side so it could be turned on / off. with a very small switch.

Comment: In my house there is a 125 to 20 V transformer mounted on a wall in the utilities closet for the HVAC and the water heater. There is an electrical box in the wall and this transformer is on the interior side. The connections for the 20 V wires are accessible.

Comment: Where on the planet are you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doorbells in Europe use mains voltage.  The far better way to do this is to disable the supply transformer or other voltage source, or disconnect the doorbell at the transformer if it shares the transformer with the furnace/thermostat.

For that matter, nothing keeps you from putting the doorbell transformer or other power source onto a cord-and-plug connection, and then stick a lamp timer into the socket.  Now the doorbell will only function the hours you specify.    You can put a sign on the doorbell to this effect.

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea!